# EditText tipo Whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp

Al ingresar texto en el `Edittext` de *whatsapp* el teclado siempre se posiciona debajo de `Edittext`, sin tapar lo que uno escribe y este `edittext` aumentan de tamaño dependiendo del cuanto texto se introduzca. ¿Alguno tiene alguna idea de como hacer esto?

Yo cuento con un *Edittext* y un *Botón* pero básico

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />
```

Comment: En el caso de wasap, y minimizando bastante, deberia estar dividido en un toolbar y en 2 LinearLayout, uno que contenga.
En el toolbar esta el avatar y titulo de la persona con la que conversas. EN el primer LinearLAyout deberia estar todo el texto ya enviado. Y el otro LinearLayout debe estar con gravity Buttom y con un edit text adentro

Comment: pero yo solo busco el comportamiento del edittext, que a medida que uno escribe va creciendo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtInput"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/compose_hint"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="2000"
    android:maxLines="4" />
```

Comment: disculpa, que significa textCapSentences

Comment: Vuelve mayúscula el primer carácter de una oración

Comment: bien, el edittext va creciendo mientras se escribe hasta el max de 4, gracias